# How to add multiple collection view in a view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to incorporate 2 collection views into same view. I implemented everything and noticed that the data that is loading in the second collection view is the same as the first collection view.

Here is the code that i am trying out

```
    class DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewCellClass: UICollectionViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewImageListingViewOutlet    : UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewLabelOutlet               : UILabel!

}

class DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewCellClass: UICollectionViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewImageListingViewOutlet    : UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewLabelOutlet               : UILabel!

}


private let reuseIdentifierDashBoardMainSection1Cell = "dashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewCellIdentifier"

private let reuseIdentifierDashBoardMainSection2Cell = "dashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewCellIdentifier"

class DashBoardViewControllerMain: UIViewController,  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{



    @IBOutlet weak var DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet    :   UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewOutlet    :   UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet.delegate = self;
        DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewOutlet.delegate = self;
        DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet.dataSource = self;
        DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewOutlet.dataSource = self;

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        var count:Int?
        if (self.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet) != nil{
            count = 10
        }
        //if (self.DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewOutlet) != nil{
        else{
            count = 5
        }

        return count!
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let collectionView = self.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet{

            let cell:DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewCellClass = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierDashBoardMainSection1Cell, for: indexPath) as! DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewCellClass


            cell.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewImageListingViewOutlet.image = UIImage(named:"Apple.png")

            cell.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewLabelOutlet.text = "FIRST"

            return cell



        }
        else{       
          let cell2:DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewCellClass = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierDashBoardMainSection2Cell, for: indexPath) as! DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewCellClass


            cell2.DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewImageListingViewOutlet.image = UIImage(named:"Logo-Disabled.png")

            cell2.DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewLabelOutlet.text = "SECOND"

            return cell2

        }
    }
```

When i run the project both the collection views are showing Apple picture and the cell count is 10.

Can someone help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your condition `if (self.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet) != nil`, will always return true and code for `if` block will only execute everytime.

Try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        var count = 0
        if (collectionView == self.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet) {
            count = 10
        }
       // if (collectionView == self.DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewOutlet)
        else {
            count = 5
        }

        return count
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       if (collectionView == self.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet){

            let cell:DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewCellClass = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierDashBoardMainSection1Cell, for: indexPath) as! DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewCellClass
            cell.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewImageListingViewOutlet.image = UIImage(named:"Apple.png")

            cell.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewLabelOutlet.text = "FIRST"
            return cell

        }
        else{       
          let cell2:DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewCellClass = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierDashBoardMainSection2Cell, for: indexPath) as! DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewCellClass
              cell2.DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewImageListingViewOutlet.image = UIImage(named:"Logo-Disabled.png")

            cell2.DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewLabelOutlet.text = "SECOND"
            return cell2

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the if statement:

It should be like this:

```
if collectionView == self.DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet{
    //code
}
```

With this code, you check if the `collectionView` passed by the parameter is the first `collectionView`.

With your original code, you were making new constant named `collectionView` and assigning it with your first `collectionView`.

Answer (score 1):

Please manage both collectionview with tag. Give tag to both collectionview on viewDidLoad method or from storyboard. Now make conditions based on tag.

**Example :-**

```
DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet.tag = 1
DashBoardMainSection2CollectionViewOutlet.tag = 2

if collectionView.tag == 1 {
   return 10
} else {
   return 5
}
```

Comment: `DashBoardMainSection1CollectionViewOutlet.tag` will always remain 1, so your if block will always return true

Comment: Update your answer with `if collectionView.tag == 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you get same data for both `UICollectionView` it means you are using the same `DataSource`.
Define a separate `DataSource` for each `UICollectionView`
And you should do the same for the Delegate except if you need to implement same actions for both.